# How do I dump an entire MongoDB database as text/json?

Tags: mongodb

How can I dump an entire MongoDB database as text (plain text, json, or CSV)?

I'm using an application I'm not too familiar with. I'd like to

- clear the database
- load seed data
- dump the whole db as text
- do some stuff
- dump again

then diff the two!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `mongoexport` utility.  It will dump out json by default but you can specify to dump out csv format.

`mongoexport --help` will give you all the options you will need.

You mentioned that you would like to dump all the collections from a database, and `mongoexport` expects you to specify a database and collection name, since it expects to dump one collection.

You can write a short shell script (if you are on Windows, convert to batch script) to the effect of:

```
#!/bin/sh
# assuming mongo bin is in your path

host=YOURMONGOHOST
port=YOURMONGOPORT
db=DBYOUWANTTOEXPORT

for c in `mongo --quiet $host:$port/$db --eval 'db.getCollectionNames()' | sed 's/,/ /g'`
do
    mongoexport --host $host --port $port -d $db -c $c > $c.json
done
```

Comment: I wish to dump *all* collections (for one database) at once. I don't see an easy way to do that with `mongoexport`. Do you?

Answer (score 22):

Using `mongodump` and `bsondump`:

**Step 1**
Dump the entire database to BSON files:

```
 mongodump --db db1
```

**Step 2**
Convert each BSON file to JSON file:

```
for f in dump/db1/*.bson; do bsondump "$f" > "$f.json"; done
```

Hope it's helps!